# How can I grep for a regex containing multiple ranges with at least one occurence

Tags: regex, bash

Given the following input I'm trying to grep for lines that begin with at least thee digits:

```
7.3M    ./user1
7.3M    ./user2
770M    ./user3
78M     ./user4
737M    ./user5
7.6M    ./user6
```

My grep command is not working:

```
grep ^[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+M
```

I don't understand why unfortunately.

Comment: Just grep for `"^[0-9][0-9][0-9]"`

Comment: where did you get the data? from `du`? many tools have the filter features to output only in certain criterial, e.g. size>100M

Comment: also good point :)

Comment: @Ben it is the right way to go, if it was in this case.  sometimes `grep` works for your current run, however it is not 100% safe and stable, it could surprise you in future. particurlarly for `ps|grep, du|grep, df|grep` those cmds.

Comment: Yeah, Frank and Kent are right, sometimes even `grep` does not support the range quantifier. I added a note in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex, `^[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+M`, *would* match the start of string (`^`), then 1+ diigts (but it does not because `+` is not compatible with POSIX BRE that you are using since there is no `-E` nor `-P` options), then again 1+ digits two times and an `M`. If you used `grep -E '^[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+M'`, it would match strings like `123M....` or `12222234421112M....`.

You may use the following POSIX BRE compatible regex:

```
grep '^[0-9]\{3\}'
```

Or a POSIX ERE compatible regex:

```
grep -E '^[0-9]{3}'
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string/line
- `[0-9]` - a digit from `0` to `9` (all ASCII digits)
- `\{3\}` / `{3}` - BRE/ERE range quantifier requiring 3 occurrences of the quantified subpattern.

**NOTE**: On Sun OS, `grep` does not support range quantifiers, so you will have to use [@FrankNeblung's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46343657/how-can-i-grep-for-a-regex-containing-multiple-ranges-with-at-least-one-occurenc/46343700#comment79647125_46343657) there, spelled out pattern like `^[0-9][0-9][0-9]`. It will also work with other tools that might not have full-fledge support for all regex quantifiers.